# Packaging a magento extension

Tags: php, magento

I have a magento script which works fine through FTP upload to store. I want to package it as an extension. I have read many articles about it but seems not to be very helpful, either due to changes on magento site or the articles are not indepth enough.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/7_-_magento_connect/packaging_a_magento_extension
http://asia-connect.com.vn/2009/07/packaging-a-magento-extension/

Anyway, how can i navigate to this page? seems its not possible. Any help? thanks.

> Admin Panel: » System » Magento Connect » Package Extensions

Comment: You don't have Package Extension in your Magento? Which version are you using? I know it's not available in Entreprise 1.8 -you'll have to package with another Magento version.

Comment: I've installed magento 1.5. Its available. I'm trying it out. Thanks

Comment: hello, whats Path: Path within the role (location)?

Comment: Roles correspond to a path in your Magento site : if you choose the role "local module" you'll be in "app/code/local", then in your "path within the role" you'll have "yourcompany/yourmodule". It's the same for other path. Hope it helps :)